# Javascript: Get last result from multiple vars with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

While trying to fix error from previous programmer I found a if function which gives the same variable multiple info which messes with our links.

```html
// This piece of script, when there is multiple 'x' selections:
if (x == 0){
  var searchBrand = ""
}
else if (x == 1) {
  var searchBrand = "one"
}
else if (x == 2) {
var searchBrand = "two"
 }
else if (x == 3) {
  var searchBrand = "three"
}
else if (x == 4) {
  var searchBrand = "four"
}
else if (x == 5) {
  var searchBrand = "five"
}

// and processed via:
var newurl = $(this).attr('href').replace('/search?q=', '/search?q=' + searchBrand + '%20'+ '%20'+ '%20');

// output in reverse order selected:
/search?q=four%20%20%20two%20%20%20five%20%20%20
```

I have tried methods like:

```html
else if (x == 3) {
  var sB = { searchBrand: three; }
}
var newurl = $(this).attr('href').replace('/search?q=', '/search?q=' + sB.searchBrand + '%20')
```

and others.

what I want to achieve is to only get the last selected x's searchBrand value in the newurl variable.

Comment: why dont just move the var declaration outside of the if else?

Answer (score 0):

Declare searchBrand variable out side of else if ladder.

```
var searchBrand = "";

// This piece of script, when there is multiple 'x' selections:
if (x == 0){
   searchBrand = "";
}
else if (x == 1) {
   searchBrand = "one";
}
else if (x == 2) {
   searchBrand = "two";
 }
else if (x == 3) {
   searchBrand = "three";
}
else if (x == 4) {
   searchBrand = "four";
}
else if (x == 5) {
   searchBrand = "five";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an array like this below

```
let searchBrand = ['','one','two','three','four','five']
var newurl = $(this).attr('href').replace('/search?q=', '/search?q=' + searchBrand[x] + '%20'+ '%20'+ '%20');

let queryParameter = ''
while(numberOfIterations){
    queryParameter = queryParameter+searchBrand[x]+'%20%20%20'
} //numberOfIterations is the number of times the value x is input
```

Also, I believe the question is not well framed. So could you reframe it better?

Comment: Have tried this with some variations as well, no luck